# Triggering a paragraph in Apache Zeppelin using z.run()

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-zeppelin

I am having some problems with Apache Zeppelin and I am not sure what I am missing, basically

I am trying to trigger a paragraph from another paragraph in Apache Zeppelin using z.run. When I run the paragraph with z.run I get no error, but the paragraph I specified is also not run. On the other hand, if I enter the wrong paragraphID on purpose, I get an error that this paragraph doesn't exit.

I have tried using `z.runParagraph`, `z.run` with spark and `z.z.run` with pyspark. However, when I copy the code from here [angular_frontend.html](https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.8.0/usage/display_system/angular_frontend.html) 
I am able to run another paragraph when filling in the paragraphID and clicking  "run paragraph".

What I am trying is the following:

```
%spark 
z.run("paragraphID")

%pyspark
print("Hello World")
```

I expect the "Hello World" will be printed, but it is not.

Comment: z.run() works only in anonymous mode.